# Closing an issue on GitHub with a commit message not working

Tags: github

I know that I can close a GitHub issue once a commit (with an appropriate message) is merged into the main branch. For some reason this is not working for me (?)

If you see [this issue](https://github.com/ALPHA-g-Experiment/alpha-g/issues/69), it is still open. You can see that there is a commit that correctly references the issue (and if you hover over the text it says "This commit closes issue #69").

Is there any reason why this didn't work? I have just started using GitHub merge queues, maybe there is an issue with this?

Comment: AFAIK that feature only works when you merge with the default branch. Check in your repository settings that `main` is the [default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch). It's also odd that the issue is not linked to the pull request.

Comment: And sometimes Github falls behind or misses an event. Try contacting support.

Comment: Yes, `main` is the default branch. Furthermore, this has worked before for me e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/ALPHA-g-Experiment/alpha-g/issues/106). Given that I just started using the new GitHub merge queues, maybe it is an issue with that, but I have no idea where would be the appropriate place to report this.

Comment: [support.github.com](https://support.github.com/) would be the place to start.